# profile willing to relocate only one location?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I am adding my Profile to Stack Exchange and I clicked on the "Willing to Relocate?" option and wanted to enter some states or areas where I am willing to go.

I tried several ways but it seems I can only add One City or State to the Locations to where I am willing to relocate!  Each time I tried "ALL" or "Anywhere" or "Southern US" it would select some State with one of the characters I entered.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I think you either have to do that yourself or convince a moderator to do it.

Comment: Thanks Sannon.Convince a moderator to move my comment? If u meant enter what I want in this field: I do not know how to do that as explained.

Comment: I would just do what you suggested: delete this one, and create the new one on meta.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84042/for-careers-relocation-how-to-specify-anywhere

Comment: @LPETEET That's the way it works currently. Each location needs to be a specific location. We don't support abstractions like "Anywhere" or "Southern US".